# Sharing Data among pthreads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads, euclidean-distance

I am new to C language programming and I am trying to learn threads with it. But I am not sure how to pass parameters among threads.
For example, I am trying to calculate the norm with this formula
[image]

In a single thread function, I can easily do it:

```
//vec is a vector array from x1 to xn
//len is the size of vec
float L2_norm_with_single_thread(const float *vec, size_t len) {
  double result= 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    result += vec[i] * vec[i];
  }
  result = sqrt(result);
  return result;
}
```

But I want to do it in multi-threads. But I am not sure how to sum the result together in a subroutine function Cal_L2_norm and return to the main function.

```
void *Cal(void *arg) { 
// not sure what I should put here to get the vector array. 
// not sure what arg is for, but I just copy from other code. 
}

float L2_norm(const float *vec, size_t len) {
  int num_of_threads = 4 //to compare the efficiency with different number of threads
  pthread_t ph[num_of_threads];
  int rc;
  float result;

  for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; i++) {
    rc = pthread_create(&ph[i], &attr[i], Cal, (void *)&args[i]);
    assert(rc == 0);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < num_of_threads; i++) {
    rc = pthread_join(ph[i], NULL);
    assert(rc == 0);
  }
  result = sqrt(result)
  return result;
 }
```

Do I need to define a struct like the following?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to pass multiple values to the thread functions then using structures and arrays of those structures is a good idea (one element per thread, passing a pointer to an element to the thread function).

Comment: Also note that in C any pointer can be implicitly converted to `void *`, you don't need an explicit cast. And the opposite is also true, you don't need to cast from `void *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global table can be split into subsets of equal sizes assigned to each threads. They receive the size of the subset, the offset of the subset in the global vector table and they will return a computation result. So, defining a structure to pass those parameters to the threads is a solution:

```c
// Thread's parameters
struct th_param {
  pthread_t tid;
  int       offset;
  size_t    nb;
  double    result;
};
```

The threads must start at the same time otherwise some threads may finish before others are created. Using a [barrier](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init) to make the thread start the computing at the "same time" is a solution. The main program initializes the barrier with the number of involved threads (this includes the main thread):

```c
// Thread synchronization
pthread_barrier_t barrier;
[...]
  // Initialize the barrier (number of secondary threads + main thread)
  rc = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, nb_threads + 1);
  if (rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_barrier_init()");
    return 1;
  }
[...]
  // Synchronize with the threads
  rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  if (rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD && rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_barrier_wait()");
    return 1;
  }
```

As you said that you are a beginner with the pthreads, note that upon error, the functions do not set `errno` but return the error code. Hence, to use `errno` in the error messages, don't forget to set `errno` with the return code of the failing pthread function. For example:

```c
rc = pthread_create(&(th_table[i].tid), NULL, th_entry, &(th_table[i]));
if (rc != 0) {
  errno = rc;
  perror("pthread_create()");
  return 1;
}
```

Then, the program can take as parameters, the number of computing threads and the vector's values:

```c
  if (ac < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s nb_threads x1 x2 x3...\n", basename(av[0]));
    return 1;
  }
```

Here is an example of source code for the program:

```c
/*

  Compute the Euclidean norm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))

*/
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libgen.h>

// Vector table
float *vec;


// Thread's parameters
struct th_param {
  pthread_t tid;
  int       offset;
  size_t    nb;
  double    result;
};

// Thread synchronization
pthread_barrier_t barrier;


void *th_entry(void *arg)
{
  struct th_param *param = (struct th_param *)arg;
  int i;
  int rc;

  param->result = 0;

  // Synchronize with the other threads
  rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  if (rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD && rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_barrier_wait()");
    return NULL;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < param->nb; i ++) {
    param->result += vec[param->offset + i] * vec[param->offset + i];
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  int              i;
  size_t           nb_vec;
  int              nb_threads;
  struct th_param *th_table;
  int              rc;
  double           result;

  if (ac < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s nb_threads x1 x2 x3...\n", basename(av[0]));
    return 1;
  }

  nb_threads = atoi(av[1]);

  if (nb_threads <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Bad number of threads\n");
    return 1;
  }

  nb_vec = ac - 2;

  if (nb_threads > nb_vec) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Too many threads\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // Allocate the vector table
  vec = (float *)malloc(nb_vec * sizeof(float));
  if (!vec) {
    perror("malloc");
    return 1;
  }

  // Allocate the per-thread parameters
  th_table = (struct th_param *)malloc(nb_threads * sizeof(struct th_param));
  if (!th_table) {
    perror("malloc");
    return 1;
  }

  // Populate the vector table
  for (i = 0; i < nb_vec; i ++) {

    vec[i] = strtof(av[i + 2], NULL);

  }

  // Initialize the barrier (number of secondary threads + main thread)
  rc = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, nb_threads + 1);
  if (rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_barrier_init()");
    return 1;
  }

  // Create the threads
  for (i = 0; i < (nb_threads - 1); i ++) {

    th_table[i].offset = i * (nb_vec / nb_threads);
    th_table[i].nb = nb_vec / nb_threads;

    printf("Thread#%d, offset=%d, nb=%zu\n", i, th_table[i].offset, th_table[i].nb);

    rc = pthread_create(&(th_table[i].tid), NULL, th_entry, &(th_table[i]));
    if (rc != 0) {
      errno = rc;
      perror("pthread_create()");
      return 1;
    }

  }

  // The last thread may have less/more slots
  th_table[i].offset = i * (nb_vec / nb_threads);
  th_table[i].nb = nb_vec / nb_threads;
  th_table[i].nb = nb_vec - (i * th_table[i].nb);

  printf("Thread#%d, offset=%d, nb=%zu\n", i, th_table[i].offset, th_table[i].nb);

  rc = pthread_create(&(th_table[i].tid), NULL, th_entry, &(th_table[i]));
  if (rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_create()");
    return 1;
  }

  result = 0;

  // Synchronize with the threads
  rc = pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
  if (rc != PTHREAD_BARRIER_SERIAL_THREAD && rc != 0) {
    errno = rc;
    perror("pthread_barrier_wait()");
    return 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nb_threads; i ++) {

    rc = pthread_join(th_table[i].tid, NULL);
    if (rc != 0) {
      errno = rc;
      perror("pthread_create()");
      return 1;
    }

    result += th_table[i].result;

  }

  result = sqrt(result);

  printf("Result=%f\n", result);

  return 0;

}
```

Built it:

```
$ gcc euclidean_norm.c -o euclidean_norm -lpthread -lm
```

Run it:

```
$ ./euclidean_norm
Usage: euclidean_norm nb_threads x1 x2 x3...
$ ./euclidean_norm 1 1 2 3
Thread#0, offset=0, nb=3
Result=3.741657
$ ./euclidean_norm 2 1 2 3
Thread#0, offset=0, nb=1
Thread#1, offset=1, nb=2
Result=3.741657
$ ./euclidean_norm 3 1 2 3
Thread#0, offset=0, nb=1
Thread#1, offset=1, nb=1
Thread#2, offset=2, nb=1
Result=3.741657
```

To measure the time duration, it is possible to use [time command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time) or for finer granularity functions like [gettimeofday()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday)...

You may also make the threads run on separate CPU cores by passing CPU affinity attributes at thread creation time as second parameter of [pthread_create](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) (cf. [pthread_attr_init](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_init)) or pass the CPU core number in the parameters and call [pthread_set_affinity_np](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setaffinity_np) in the thread's entry point.

You may also consider setting the scheduling policy/priority of the threads with [pthread_setschedparam](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setschedparam) or the aforementioned thread's attributes.

When implementing data structures for multi-threaded applications, there is a common pitfall consisting to forget or underestimate the impact of the [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) on the performances. That is why data structure alignments on cache line sizes is also an important concern (e.g. `gcc` provides the [aligned](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) attribute). In the application example above, when a thread writes its results into the parameter structure, it may trigger **false sharing** with the other threads if contiguous parameter structures share the same cache lines. To solve this with `gcc`, we can use the `aligned` attribute to make each entry of the table of parameters be on a separate cache line. One way to get the cache line size if to look at `/proc/cpuinfo`:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep cache_alignment
cache_alignment : 64
[...]
```

The structure could be redefined as:

```c
// Thread's parameters
struct th_param {
  pthread_t tid;
  int       offset;
  size_t    nb;
  double    result;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));
```